# Query Table (Snowflake) refresh does not work in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing a VBA code to refresh my queried table, save it and send it as attachment in email. This VBA code will be scheduled to run daily so I will not be opening the excel file manually, hence I need to use my VBA code to execute all the tasks. My queried table has a data source connected to my Snowflake table, and it is currently just a dummy table to test with only 1 column and 5 rows. I inserted new rows in my table and tried to use my VBA code to refresh the queried table in excel with my code below. I know it is attempting to refresh the query table, because when I look at Data >  Queries & Connections, it gave me a message that 'Download did not complete.' When I hit refresh manually, it took only 2 seconds to load the data. I'm not sure what is happening? Or does anyone have an alternative way to refresh query table in VBA code that will be scheduled without opening the excel file?

[image]

My Code:

```
'Delay for the table to load.
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:01:00")

'Refresh all the data in other sheets
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```